# How to pull changes from another branch into my branch?

Tags: git, github, git-branch, branching-and-merging

I have 3 to 4 branches in a git repository , my branch is **test_priya**. someone has made changes in branch **test_ankita**, now before I do any coding changes in my branch(test_priya) I want to have all the changes from test_ankita into my branch .
How do I do it ?

Comment: try to `git pull origin test_ankita` or fetch and merge or checkout test_ankita in local and pull the remote branch test_ankita and merge in local.@codette

Answer (score 0):

You can merge the branch, one other way to do this using rebase would be :

```
git checkout test_priya
git fetch
git rebase origin/test_ankita
```

Answer (score 0):

git merge "branchName"

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).